# NHibernate session.saveOrUpdate takes a long time

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-migrator

I have the below mapping of data, everything is mapped correctly for each mode

```
public DataMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().UnsavedValue(0);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CreatedTime).Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.SourceData)
            .Not.KeyNullable()
            .KeyColumn("SourceId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.LinkData)
            .Not.KeyNullable()
            .KeyColumn("LinkDataId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.ImageData)
            .Not.KeyNullable()
            .KeyColumn("ImageDataId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.Configuration)
            .Not.KeyNullable()
            .KeyColumn("ConfigurationId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
        Map(x => x.Enabled).Not.Nullable();
    }
```

during the save `session.SaveOrUpdate(Data)` it takes it a long time for everything to be saved.
Note that all foreign keys are indexed, and tried to use merge instead of SaveOrUpdate. but the result are the same.

Is there anyway to improve the transaction or the mapping for a better performance ?

Comment: When you say "everything", how many rows are you saving, are those pure inserts or do you have the also updates?

On a more helpful note: are you using an explicit or implicit Transaction for the operation?

Sidenote: when saving bulk data, indexes are actually slowing down the operation (depends on the form or the save). Therefore a common practice is dropping the indexes, FKs, etc. then saving the data and finishing with recreating the constraints again.

Comment: the attempted rows are more than 1000 for each table referenced in Data, at this instance its only pure insert of data no update, yet its taking some time to save the records. the indexing also happen during migration automatically by FluentMigrator

Comment: do you have an ability to see the emitted sql? (e.g. through SQLServer Profiler or just through logs from the framework)

Comment: yess, it seems like the its adding by order one row at a  time, source data, then link data.. is there a way to make it insert by bulk ?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about nhibernate nor FluentMigrator, but my guess is that this behavior is by design: the SourceData contains other entities and by saving one SourceData, all other subentities are saved at the same time. But I'd say that this should not be that impactful anyway (but I might be wrong). Therefore a more important question is: is the delay in DB by processing these commands or in nHibernate by traversing the mapped objects?

Comment: Can you check `session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntityEntries` if there are other entities from other operations which slows down the check for changes. There is `session.Evict()` und `session.Clear()` to remove not needed entities from the cache.

Comment: I have solved this issue by using sqlBulkCopy and updating one of the mapping. I had big data so there was no way I could improve the performance with only nhibernate